# symfony doctrine one-two-many index problem

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Having a the paradigm :
- stations could have 0..N forecast models associated.
- each forecast model could have 0..N stations related.

It means **stations** and **forecasts** tables get related by the in between table named **station_forecast**.

Following code fails shooting the error when twig file try to read the forecasts collection from a station object:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template

> Notice: Undefined index: ***station*** in /vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1280

**Station**:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ForecastBundle\Entity\StationForecast", mappedBy="***station***")   <-- THIS 'STATION' THE ERROR REFERS.
 */
protected $forecasts`;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->forecasts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
function getForecasts() {
    return $this->forecasts;
}

/**
 * @param \ForecastBundle\Entity\StationForecast $station_forecast
 */
public function addForecasts(StationForecast $station_forecast)
{
    $this->forecasts[] = $station_forecast;
}
```

**StationForecast**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="station_id", type="integer", nullable=false)  
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EstacionsBundle\Entity\Station", inversedBy="forecasts")
 */
protected $station;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="forecast_id", type="integer", nullable=false)  
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ForecastBundle\Entity\Forecast", inversedBy="stations")
 */
protected $forecast;
```

**Forecast**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ForecastBundle\Entity\StationForecast", mappedBy="forecast")
 */
protected $stations;

public function addEstacions(\ForecastBundle\Entity\StationForecast $stations)
{
    $this->stations[] = $stations;
}

/**
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getStations()
{
    return $this->stations;
}

public function addStationForecast(\ForecastBundle\Entity\StationForecast $stations)
{
    $this->stations[] = $stations;
}
```

Do you know what could happen? I'm getting crazy...

Comment: Format your code in question to follow up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need the **StationForcast** class at all! Just keep **Station** & **Forcast**, and doctrine will still create and manage the joint table (station_forcast) for you.

**Station**

```
class Station
{
    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Forcast", mappedBy="stations")
     */
    protected $forecasts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->forecasts = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection 
     */
    function getForecasts() {
        return $this->forecasts;
    }

    /**
     * @param Forecast $forecast
     */
    public function addForecast(Forecast $forecast)
    {
        if (!$this->forcasts->contains($forcast)
        {
            $this->forecasts->add($forecast);
            $forcast->addStation($this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Forcast**

```
class Forcast
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Station", inversedBy="forecasts")
     */
    protected $stations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->stations = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection 
     */
    public function getStations()
    {
        return $this->stations;
    }

    /**
     * @param Station $station
     */
    public function addStation(Station $station)
    {
        if (!$this->stations->contains($station)
        {
            $this->stations->add($station);
            $station->addForcast($this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! But how does Doctrine knows the name of the in the middle table? And its foreign keys fields names? Doing what you suggested, symfony returns '' ("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'forecast_station' doesn't exist" '' because the right one is 'station_forecast'. Do I have to use any annotation to indicate it all (fk fields and table names)?

Comment: Doctrine combines the name of the two entities and creates the middle table. Gets the foreign key names from the association (ManyToMany) combined with `_id`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! @Trix